# Gamepad PoV control going to sleep

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx, joystick, gamepad

When polling my gamepad and it does nothing for a a minute or two the PoV control goes into some sort of sleep mode and returns nothing, but selected a button wakes it up.  Is this normal and is there a way to keep the PoV from sleeping?

Ckeckbox activation....

```
  private void CheckBoxJoystick_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckboxJoystick.IsChecked.HasValue & CheckboxJoystick.IsChecked == true)
        {
            var windowHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
            _gamepad = new Gamepad(windowHandle);
            if (!_gamepad.IsAvailable) return;
            ctsGamepad?.Cancel();
            ctsGamepad = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoGamepadWork, ctsGamepad.Token);
        }
    }
```

Main loop to poll the gamepad...

```
  private void DoGamepadWork(object obj)
    {
        if (!_gamepad.IsAvailable) return;
        var token = (CancellationToken)obj;
        var buttontocheck = -1;
        var povtocheck = new PovPair(-1,0);
        while (true)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
            _gamepad.Poll();
            // Check buttons...
            // Check PoVs...
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Polling Gamepad....

```
    public void Poll()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsAvailable) return;
            joystick.Acquire();
            joystick.Poll();
            State = joystick.GetCurrentState();
            Buttons = State.Buttons;
            Povs = State.PointOfViewControllers;
            Datas = joystick.GetBufferedData();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {            }
    }
```

Finds attached Gamepads...

```
    private void Find()
    {
        foreach (var deviceInstance in directInput.GetDevices(DeviceType.Gamepad, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AttachedOnly))
            joystickGuid = deviceInstance.InstanceGuid;

        // If Gamepad not found, look for a Joystick
        if (joystickGuid == Guid.Empty)
            foreach (var deviceInstance in directInput.GetDevices(DeviceType.Joystick, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AttachedOnly))
                joystickGuid = deviceInstance.InstanceGuid;

        // If Joystick not found
        if (joystickGuid == Guid.Empty)
        {
            IsAvailable = false;
            return;
        }

        // Instantiate the joystick
        joystick = new Joystick(directInput, joystickGuid);
        joystick.SetCooperativeLevel(hWnd, CooperativeLevel.Background | CooperativeLevel.NonExclusive);

        // Set BufferSize in order to use buffered data.
        joystick.Properties.BufferSize = 128;

        // Acquire the joystick
        joystick.Acquire();
        IsAvailable = true;
        Load_Settings();
    }
```

Comment: could we see the global loop, maybe you block your UI? normally the acquire is done only One time, or if the acquire is lost..

Comment: Modified the original post and put in main logic.  Not blocking the UI and the State reports no PoV data until it wakes.  As far as the acquire.  I was doing it just once and would get an not acquired error every now and then, doing it each time stopped that, but not sure if it could be causing this issue. I don't think it's the issue because the buttons work all the time. -- Thanks

Comment: sorry i dont see the framework you are using for gamepad?  directinput, xna? could you precise

Comment: SharpDX.DirectInput;

Comment: ok could you display the Gamepad class, i would know how do you do the enumeration of controllers, the cooperative level you are using...

Comment: Modified the original post and added the code for find .   Should be what your looking for.  --Thanks

Comment: is there a reason you are using the nonexclusive in cooperativeLevel??? you have only one program which needs the stick or more programs?.

Comment: Less errors.... because nonexclusive access to the device is always permitted, even if another application has obtained exclusive access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183140/discussion-between-frenchy-and-rob-morgan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a functional example, i select the first stick...  the button 0 stops the loop and i test the pov[0]

```
using SharpDX.DirectInput;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var controller = new Controller();
        }
    }

    public class Controller
    {
        private Task pollingTask;
        private bool running;

        private JoystickState state;

        public JoystickState State => state ?? (state = controller.GetCurrentState());
        public Joystick controller;
        public Controller()
        {
            var directInput = new DirectInput();
            var handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
            var diDevices = directInput.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AttachedOnly);
            controller = new Joystick(directInput, diDevices[0].InstanceGuid);
            controller.SetCooperativeLevel(handle, CooperativeLevel.Exclusive | CooperativeLevel.Background);
            controller.Acquire();
            running = true;
            PollJoystick();

            if (pollingTask != null)
            {
                pollingTask.Wait();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("fini");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        TimeSpan period = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30);
        public int[] Pov => State.PointOfViewControllers;
        public bool stop => State.Buttons[0];
        public void PollJoystick()
        {
            pollingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                while (running)
                {
                    state = null;
                    running = !stop;
                    if (Pov[0] != -1)
                        Console.WriteLine(Pov[0]);
                    Task.Delay(period);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I did convert what I had over to a Task.Run(() but the pov and axis are still going to sleep.  Not sure if this will solve that but I'll try it out.

Comment: have you the same thing if you use my program ?

Comment: I found out the gampepad I have does have a sleep mode, but your answer is very useful in the way you deal with State and no polling.